# Needing help executing a windows form C# app off a thumb drive

Tags: c#, windows, forms, path, parent

I'm new to C# and am having trouble executing my app off a thumb drive.  My code on my computer is as follows

```
    private void buttonanticipation_Click(object sender, 
    EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer sPlayer = new SoundPlayer (@"C:\Users\MyPC\SoundBoardApp\Soundboards\AnticipationSound.wav");
            sPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonrecordscreech_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer sPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\MyPC\SoundBoardApp\Soundboards\RecordScreetch.wav");
        sPlayer.Play();
    }
```

But all I need it to do is find the path designated on the flash drive.  On my PC the path is D: but it varies on other computers.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have coded your program to look always for that path then you will not be able to fix the problem without recompiling your code. You need to use the [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-app-config-file?view=vs-2017) file to resolve these issues

Comment: Compile the resources into your executable image. There doesn't appear to be an immediate need to have those on disk. Unless those are 3rd-party assets. In that case we cannot make any recommendations as we have no way of knowing, where they reside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is somewhere inside your Application's folder you can use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Soundboards\\RecordScreetch.wav");
SoundPlayer sPlayer = new SoundPlayer(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place the soundboards folder where your .exe is located. Then, get the path to the exe directory by:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Then just add the path to the file:

```
path += "/Soundboards/RecordScreetch.wav";
```